# Need help developing an interactive menu with jquery

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS,HTML and Ajax.

I have developed a page using HTML and CSS.

[image]

What I want to do is,If I will click on Leave Information then it should display another 3 options like DashBoard,Action,Report. (i want to use jquery to do it)

This should come in the same table below to the Leave information,this 3 options should display.Is it possible to do in jquery?

How i can solve this problem ? (i don't want to use any extra page)

Coding i have done

**HTML**

```
  <table border="2" id="Official_Page_Leftside_Table" name="lefttable" bgcolor="#408080" >
      <tr><td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Master Data</td></tr>
      <tr><td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Projects</td></tr>
      <tr><td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leave Information</td></tr>
  </table>
```

**CSS**

```
 #Official_Page_Leftside_Table
       {
         width:150px;
         left:5px;
         float:left;
         top:140px;
         font-size:16px;
         position:absolute;
      }
```

Comment: It seems you have mixed up some things. Which is understandable, since you have to work with different topics to achieve what you want to do. 1. It seems you use table to layout your documents, this seems to be easier at the beginning, but I promise you it will be a massive help for you, to start layouting without tables. 2. Ajax OR jQuery is not a question since jQuery is a Javascript-Framework that can (amongst other things) help you using ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: "Trying to use ajax in html" is very unlikely to help any future readers. please consider adding a meaningful title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you dont need Ajax for what you trying to achieve. We can do it simply using jquery. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf7L/)**

```
$('.otherOption').click(function(){
    $('.otherActions').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: thats bcoz of empty tr if you dont want then use this : http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf7L/1/ or use this http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf7L/2/

Comment: yes now its working fine what i was expecting...another thing i am not getting is ,if we are giving anything inside a <tr><td>,then it will be separate by a line why not the second table ?if it will come like the first 3 options then it will be better ? can you tell me that?

Comment: will u check the last question...i have done this http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf7L/4/  ..how to remove the last above 2 line ...

Comment: not getting .. what do you mean by last above 2 lines?

Comment: no actually in jsfiddle if i am changing anything it is not saving the data , so the above link is not showing proper output,what i have done is i removed this .linksLeft tr.last td { border-bottom:0px;} and done like this .linksLeft tr td { border-bottom:1px solid #414141; padding:10px;} and removed the class="last"  from the html file. Then you check it, you will able to see 2 lines before the bottom border.That 2 line i want to remove...

Comment: Have you checked out  ?

Comment: I dont knw if i am getting your query exactly.. but is this u r looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/Vvf7L/5/

Comment: hufffff.. finally.. :D

Comment: Will u help me out , i have some doubt ?

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation..We have this .  http://i.stack.imgur.com/AHX47.jpg page ,what i am trying to do is ,if i will click on Action then some content will come in the middle of the page.  <div id="Official_Action">Leave Information</div> ,css code #Official_Action{display:none;left:230px;top:270px;position:absolute;} when i will click it should display . I made the Leave information to invisible state how to visible to that content.(How i can share the code with you,which will be easier for you,is there any way.)

Answer (score 0):

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82c2V/1/)**

You create a list for 'Leave Information' and hide the `<li>` elements using `visibility: none` or `display: none`. Then use Javascript or jQuery to bind an event (e.g. hover/click/mouseover) to change the CSS of these `<li>` elements to `visibility: visible` or `display: block`.

**Avoid using tables unless it actually is tabulated data, which this is not. Use lists (or nav in HTML5) instead. It is better to use CSS to style a list rather than use tables because 'it looks like buttons'.**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Master Data</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li class="hide">Leave Information
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".hide").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).children().css({"visibility": "visible"});
  }, function() {
    $( this ).children().css({"visibility": "hidden"});
  }
);
```

Alternatively, you can bond the event to an element, and use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) or [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to remove the class which hides it. This method can be extended to allow for things such as changing the colour of the button on `mouseover`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add this html in body

```
<table border="2" id="Official_Page_Leftside_Table" name="lefttable" bgcolor="#408080">
        <tr>
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Master Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Projects</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="ShowLeaveInfo()">
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leave Information</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="leaveinfo">
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dash Board</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="leaveinfo">
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="leaveinfo">
            <td height="35px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Report</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Following JavaScript in Head section.Remember to add latest jquery file jquery.js

```
function ShowLeaveInfo() {
            $(".leaveinfo").slideToggle();
        }
```

Following Style Sheet

```
<style type="text/css">
        .leaveinfo {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Its All Done.